# Nodes being imported from the Feed module not being published

Tags: feeds

I have finally accomplished the communication between my 2 websites through the Feed module. I am exporting xml and I am using the XPath XML Parser to receive the nodes. The problem that I have now is that it is only updating nodes that have been previously imported through the feed, even though some of that content was already on the other website. The ones that are being imported are left with the Unpublished status, even though they were initially published on the website that exported them. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this might sound way too easy but have you been into the content type you are importing to and made sure that it is set to default published? Unless you tell the imported nodes otherwise, they will use the default for the content type. If you are using the published status from the xml as the published status for the imported nodes, then thats another matter.

Comment: Hi 7wonders. Thank you for your answer. My content type is published by default :/  I did include the published status in the xml, but I don't know why it is not being published.

Comment: And the status you are importing from the xml is definitely a zero (0) or one (1)? I would try deleting all the nodes through the importer, delete the import (not the importer), clearing the cache and then re-importing.

Comment: this is what I get off the feed: <Published>Yes</Published>

Comment: Its possible that your problem is in that Yes instead of 1. Create a small test feed and replace all Yes' with 1's and all No's with 0's and see if that helps. If it does help then there is your problem. To fix the problem use feeds_tamper module and set it up to rewrite all Yes as 1's and all No's as 0's.

Comment: Replacing it to 1 actually got it working. Thank you for your help!