# Import xml data

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I am new to drupal. To import xml data into drupal, i followed these steps given in this website which i mentioned it below.

http://www.drupalprogrammer.co.uk/2012/12/use-feeds-module-to-import-xml-data-in.html

After doing all these things, it shows **"There are no new nodes."**

Can any one pls give me an idea or solution to import xml data into drupal 7.26?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodes being imported from the Feed module not being published](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20777/nodes-being-imported-from-the-feed-module-not-being-published). Also, please edit your question to make it independent on external resources. Tell us **what you did**. Don't ask us to go and read manuals outside Drupal Answers and Drupal.org - content there can change or disappear without warning rendering your questions or our answers nonsense. That's something we don't want to see happening.

Comment: Feeds is successfully used by over 60000 sites. Instead of looking for an alternative straight away, I would try to solve the problem you are having with feeds. Do you have any content when you go to the admin content listing at /admin/content ?

Comment: Feeds can be a bit difficult / tricky to set up at first – the first time I used it it took me hours/days to bend it the way I needed it. Then importing 10k nodes went quite smoothly. It's worth digging deeper …

Answer (score 0):

Feeds is a very old way to import contents into Drupal. You must use the Migrate module (with Migrate extras) for import all type of contents from some different sources. 
Read the base migrate documentation (https://drupal.org/migrate) and after that try this: https://drupal.org/node/1152156
This is the better approach for import somethings (the module is integrated in Drupal 8 for its power)

Comment: This is not true at all. Feeds is still perfectly acceptable for importing from xml. In some cases migrate is better and in some cases feeds is better. It depends what you need to do.

Comment: Feeds has a lot of problems with Entity Translations and File Entity. Migrated and migrated extras instead solve these problems

Comment: But the question says nothing about translations and is importing nodes, not file entities. and the way you have worded your answer says "You must use the migrate module..." and that feeds is no good anymore because it is old, neither of which are true. You would be better to mention in your answer these things that the migrate module potentially does better, but they are still both very valid approaches. Also the feeds module is still actively maintained even though it has been around for a while.

Comment: Also, full entity handling has now been added to the feeds module so it should work for file entities. I have used it for other entity api entities via the data module in the past by using the patch that has now been committed. There are also a number of issues in progress for translation support so that is something that will likely come at some point. - There is also the fact the the migrate module is enormously more complex to use than feeds and is not really accessible to non coders because you have to code your migrations, you can't just click around the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Context, it will be "/Orders/Order", change it and nodes will be imported. This will solve the problem.